# How to bypass the hosts file when doing an nslookup in Java using InetAddress

Tags: java, dns, reverse, hosts, inetaddress

Is it possible to force Java to ignore the hosts file when doing a DNS lookup (or reverse DNS lookup)?

I have been looking into how to perform an `nslookup`in Java for quite a while, and all examples I can find end up using some variation of this command:

`InetAddress.getByName("123.12.12.12").getCanonicalHostName();`

The problem I'm having is that the response being returned is taken from the Windows hosts file, not a true `nslookup`.  If I remove the entry from my hosts file, then I get the correct result returned, but as soon as I put the entry back in the hosts file, the program returns the value from the hosts file.

If you're wondering why I'm trying to do this it is because I need to run this program on a server where I don't have the ability to modify the hosts file - it is a production server at a large company, and modifications to the hosts file will cause many applications to break.  The problem is that I need to get the actual host name which would be returned from `nslookup`, not the value from the hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to change this behaviour through the `InetAddress` class.

Java Doc [InetAddress](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)

> Host name-to-IP address resolution is accomplished through the use of
>   a combination of local machine configuration information and network
>   naming services such as the Domain Name System (DNS) and Network
>   Information Service(NIS)

It looks like Java is relying on the resolver library.
[Understanding host name resolution and DNS behavior in Java](http://www.myhowto.org/java/42-understanding-host-name-resolution-and-dns-behavior-in-java/)

Maybe could you try to configure the Name Service Switch configuration file `nsswitch.conf` in order to reorder the resolver strategy ?

Comment: Jeandey - I'm running on Windows, so there is no nsswitch.conf file.  Even so, I won't be able to change any config files on the production server, so that won't help me.  Thanks!